# What is the vector corresponding to a two-particle product state $|\psi\rangle_1|\psi\rangle_2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-states

Let's suppose we have two particles described by 
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle_1 =  \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}_1 \text{ and } |\psi\rangle_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}_2
\end{equation}
If the particles don't interact the product state $|\psi\rangle$ of both states describes the whole system.
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle_1 |\psi\rangle_2 
\end{equation}
If I know want to write the state like a vector, I get following
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle =\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Is this the correct way of doing this? Assuming both one-particle states have length $1$, we get
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2+|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2}=2
\end{equation}
Obviously the product state should be normed! What is the right way to fix this? Should we define the product state as follows
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
or should we redefine the length of the vector like this
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2} \cdot \sqrt{|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2} = 1
\end{equation}
Or are both approaches possible? Or are both wrong? Never really found something in the literature because they all stick to the bracket notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your prescription is incorrect. The state you've written down is the (external) [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of the two separate vector spaces, but independent quantum particles are described by states in the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of their individual state spaces.

Thus, if you write each of the states as $|\psi_1\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, then the joint state of the two particles is the tensor product
\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle
& = |\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle \\
& = \left( a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle \right) \otimes \left( \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle \right) \\
& = a\alpha |00\rangle + a\beta |01\rangle + b\alpha |10\rangle + b\beta |11\rangle.
\end{align}
There is no canonical way to write down this vector as a column vector, or, more specifically, there is some give-and-take in how you order the states of the product basis $\{|00\rangle , |01\rangle, |10\rangle ,|11\rangle\}$. That ordering is common in quantum information, where it's known as the 'computational basis', but other orderings are possible. If you do take that ordering, then $|\psi\rangle$ corresponds to the column vector
$$
|\psi\rangle 
\leftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} a\alpha \\ a\beta \\ b\alpha \\ b\beta \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Inner products in the tensor-product space work much as you'd expect, i.e. via
$$
\left< \vphantom{\sum} |u\rangle\otimes |v\rangle, |w\rangle\otimes |x\rangle \right>
=
\langle u|w\rangle  \langle v|x\rangle,
$$
which means that the computational basis is orthonormal. Among other things, this means that the tensor product of two unit-norm states also has unit norm:
\begin{align}
\langle \psi|\psi \rangle
& = |a\alpha|^2 + |a\beta|^2  + |b\alpha|^2  + |b\beta|^2 
\\ & = \left( |a|^2+|b|^2\right)\left( |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2\right)
\\ & = 1\times 1 = 1.
\end{align}

Comment: " (external) direct sum" do you mean external link?

Comment: @Cheng No, I mean external direct sum, as opposed to the internal direct sum of two subspaces within a larger vector space. The distinction is explicitly addressed in the Wikipedia link provided.

Answer (score 5):

The tensor product of two 2-entry vectors is *not simply* a 4-entry vector and does not behave like it, e.g. when you think about things as simple addition of two such objects. For example,

$$\left( \begin{array}{c}  a \\ b  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  c \\ d  \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{c}  a \\ b  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  e \\ f  \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c}  a \\ b  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  c+e \\ d+f  \end{array} \right) \neq \left( \begin{array}{c}  a+a \\ b+b  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  c+e \\ d+f  \end{array} \right).$$

This gets even worse with the norm or things like this since the right norm is the product of the norms of the two vectors:

$$ \left\| \left( \begin{array}{c}  a \\ b  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  c \\ d  \end{array} \right) \right\| = \left\| \left( \begin{array}{c}  a \\ b  \end{array} \right) \right\|_1 \cdot \left\| \left( \begin{array}{c}  c \\ d  \end{array} \right) \right\|_2. $$

There is actually a way of rewriting a tensor product of two vectors  as one vector, but in a different way than you did. The tensor product of our spaces is four-dimensional, with a basis e.g. given as

$$ \left( \begin{array}{c}  1 \\ 0  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{c}  1 \\ 0  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{c}  0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{c}  0 \\ 1  \end{array} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{array}{c}  0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right) .$$

In this basis, the four-entry vector from your question correctly reads

$$ \left( \begin{array}{c}  a \alpha \\ a \beta \\ b \alpha \\ b \beta  \end{array} \right) $$

and now you can compute the norm the usual way:

$$ \sqrt{  a^2 \alpha^2 + a^2 \beta^2 + b^2 \alpha^2 + b^2 \beta^2 } = 1.$$